# Animating Constraints : Working on the "View as iPhone" in IB but not other iPhones

Tags: swift, autolayout

I am trying to animate constraints. It works perfectly on iPhone SE, but not on iPhone 7,6,8 etc.

**BIG EDIT :**

[image]

After hours of trying to fix it, I understood that when i go in IB and choose view as iPhone 8, it works perfectly on iPhone 8 when I launch and simulate it. When I chose iPhone SE, it works perfectly on SE. 
I don't get it ?? Interface Builder's preview should not impact the simulation ?!

My view is like that :

[image]

The animation is on the UIImageView. There is no link in constraints between the UIImageView and the label :
The image has X and Y constraints to align it on the center of the screen, and height and width constraints that I animate with the following code :

```
 func animate() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0,
                   delay:0.0,
                   options: .curveEaseIn ,
                   animations:{

                    self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = 240.0
                    self.imageWidthConstraint.constant = 240.0
                    self.imageAlignYAxes.constant = 0

                    self.logoImage.center.x = (self.view.frame.width)/2
                    self.logoImage.center.y = (self.view.frame.height)/2

                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


        },
       completion:nil)

    animateTwo()

}
```

The image was moving from the center until I added this code :

```
                        self.imageAlignYAxes.constant = 0
```

But now it is the label just down the image that moves, but ONLY on iPhone 6,6s, 7,7+, etc, 8 not on the SE.On the SE it works perfectly fine the label doesn't move.

I am working on the storyboards with the SE model, I guess this is why it works on SE but I don't get why the animation moves the label whereas it should not.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aks helped me solve the problem in a private discussion. All the credits and the congrats should come to him ! Thanks again for your really appreciated help, Aks :)

So here it is, in the UIView.animate  :

```
self.logoImage.layoutIfNeeded()
```

instead of

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

No need to apply layoutIfNeeded to the entire view, but only to the element we want to animate...

Answer (score 1):

Check the constraint you are animating, maybe you have enabled these constraints specific to device only.

With example project, I found out that issue was with `layoutIfNeeded()`. As you are only changing constraints to `UIImageView`, `layoutIfNeeded()` should be called on that view only.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! How do I know if it is enabled to device only?

Comment: In your storyboard, select your constraint and check the Property Viewer, there you will find, if the constraint is applied to specific device size.

Comment: Check out these links:- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html
https://medium.com/@craiggrummitt/size-classes-in-interface-builder-in-xcode-8-74f20a541195

Comment: Have you checked the links I provided, you will get the idea how constraints can be specific to a size class?

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example project, need more information to debug the issue.

Comment: I sent it to you in the discussion